# Error You have an error in your SQL syntax

Tags: python, sql

When I do the following request I get the message :

**(1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '>= DATEADD(MONTH, -3, GETDATE())' at line 1").**

The request is :

```
'SELECT creationdate ' \
       'FROM panel' \
       'WHERE creationdate >= DATEADD(MONTH, -3, GETDATE())' \
```

This request works when I remove the WHERE line, however when I replace it (as a test) by 'LIMIT 10' , I get the same error...

What I would want to get the last 3 months of records.

Some help would be welcome please, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing a space after `panel`, so MySQL sees `"FROM panelWHERE"`, which certainly is a syntax error:

```
>>> 'SELECT creationdate ' \
...        'FROM panel' \
...        'WHERE creationdate >= DATEADD(MONTH, -3, GETDATE())'
'SELECT creationdate FROM panelWHERE creationdate >= DATEADD(MONTH, -3, GETDATE())'
#                              ^ There!
```

Turn

```
'FROM panel' \
```

to

```
'FROM panel ' \
```

(like you had done with `'SELECT creationdate '` already).

Comment: Speaking about a small mistake... thank you sir !